# Trying to dual boot windows with (unsuccefull) Ubuntu broke windows booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I don't know where to start with explaining, but shortly, I think I made a big mess of my system.

I did not have an USB on me so I googled and found a way to dual boot by making a partition on my hard disk and booting from there, I left 200GB for ubuntu itself.

The first mistake I made (I think) is that I booted it with EFI, I got a few errors during the installation, followed a few tutorials and had a SWAP, EFI and Root/Home partions (probably some unnecessary). I ended up with the installation stuck on the same thing for 6 hours and closed it. I think I also accidently made all those partions on the same partion as where the ISO was put on.
Also I should probably add that during the installation it did not give me the option to dual boot, it did not detect any other OS.

After that I could not get back into my windows, it loaded in automatically into a GRUB screen, I tried going into the boot selection screen and tried every single one, none go to Windows and one of them goes into the Ubuntu selection screen (Install/try, Install/try+safe graphics, OEM something, EUFI select <- which did not work)

After (I feel like) breaking half my PC I tried to install it on an USB instead which I had the option for to Boot into legacy mode, now I'm running into a few other problems, it tells me it cant run the installation cause it can not unmount /cdrom (which looking at the size is the bootable partition I made on my HDD with an Ubuntu iso on it).I have 3 Ubuntu's in my boot options now which all don't work and all are only selectable from the EFI part.

I tried to go into the trial mode and download the yanbuntu (or something) boot repair but it keeps telling me that it deletes grub 2 and it might be risky and if im really sure that I would continue, I dont wanna take to big of a risk.

I also can not get windows back to where it was since it was an old Windows 7 Pro which they dont give Iso's for anymore so I cant run the repair tool.

Im trying to install the latest ubuntu 22.04.4, I put it on my usb using balenaEtcher.

I'm sorry for the massive lap of text, but I would be super happy if someone could help me to try and fix my mess. Thanks!

Comment: With any major change, you need to have backups. Then recovery is relatively easy if an user makes a mistake or hardware fails. You need extenal flash drives for repairs, both Widnows repairs with its repair/recovery flash drive that you make from inside Windows and Ubuntu live installer. Lets see what is where. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair